# How to use a different list number format in TOC?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2010

I would like the major headings in my MS Word 2010 document to be formatted as:

**Chapter 1**

**Introduction**

My list number style does this — so far so good. However, I want the TOC to omit the word "chapter" and say simply:

**1 Introduction**

How can I have this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a spectific style for Chapter 1 that you won't refer into your TOC.

More info can be found here : http://sbarnhill.mvps.org/WordFAQs/TOCTips.htm#Content

**[EDIT]** More explanation about including style :

What i meant is explained here : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/285059/en-us on the *Removing a Heading from the Table of Contents* part. That is to say, you will set a current style for Chapter 1 (say "Heading unTOC" that you would have created elsewhere) and another style for Introduction (say "Heading 1").

Then, when you create your TOC, you can choose which style you want to include (by default, Word will include only numeroted styles : Heading 1, Heading 2, and so on).

This way, only *Introduction* will be added to the TOC and *Chapter 1* won't.

Besides, i can see it does not fully answer what you asked because you wanted to keep also the **1**. For this part, i can't see an easy way to do it.

Regards,

Max

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "refer into your TOC".

Comment: sorry for not being clear. i'll edit my answer

Comment: Ah, but your solution would require me to type "Chapter 1" in by hand. I would want to keep the numbering automatic. It would be nice, if I could type only "Chapter" in manually, but numbering styles don't let me add anything in front.

Comment: you can use the ListNum Field to automate the numbering of your Chapter (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q162895/). You can style fields the way you want (Heading...)

Comment: In that case, I can't tie numbering to the heading structure. But it looks like the best compromise available.